# Conditional apex output field

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforcedx, sobject, table

I have a data table in a visualforce page where I would like to display "nothing here" if my sObject field is empty, but if there is something written inside i would like to display it.
i was trying something like this but it doesnt work:

`{!if(Custom_Object__c.field__c = ISBLANK(), "nothing here", {!Custom_Object__c.field__c}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax would be to use the `IF` statement, then check `ISBLANK` in condition like `ISBLANK(Custom_Object__c.field__c)`. And you do not have to use a merge field inside a merge field, so everything goes inside single merge field `{!YourValue}`.

Try this:

```
{!IF(ISBLANK(Custom_Object__c.field__c), "nothing here", Custom_Object__c.field__c)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! have a nice day @Raul